# how to convert filtered ListCollectionView to dataview

Tags: wpf, dataview, listcollectionview

How can I convert a filtered ListCollectionView to a dataview?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean a `System.Data.DataView`?  If so, you first have to create a `DataTable` and populate it, which means that you also need a way of converting each item in your list into a `DataRow`.

If this isn't what you mean, you need to provide a lot more detail with your question.